# Git: all files are in a subdirectory, but they should be top-level

Tags: git

This is the anatomy of a wordpress plugin:

```
.twitter-plugin
|-images/
|-index.php
+-README
```

The directory `twitter-plugin` must be placed in a well known location (`wp-content/plugins`) so Wordpress can scan it and if it founds a `README`, well it's a valid plugin. Unfortunately when I `cd` to `plugins` directory and clone a repository from Gitorious, I get:

```
.twitter-plugin
+-twitter-plugin
 |-images/
 |-index.php
 +-README
```

The plugin developer didn't put the files straight in the top level dir, but keeps them in a subdirectory named after the project. This way Wordpress can't find the plugin (it looks for `twitter/README`, instead there is `twitter/twitter/README`). I could overcome this by cloning one directory above (in `wp-content` instead of `wp-content/plugins`) but it feels hackish, has the clear disadvantage that I'll have to ignore all other plugins directories, plus Git will complain that the `plugins/` directory already exists (so I'll have to temporary move things around to make it work).

Is there a way to recover this situation? Am I missing something **fundamental** about git?

At this moment all I think I can do is init a new repository, put the files in, and try to import the history somehow. But this way I won't be able to push to the original repository - right? - because all file paths would be different

My objective is **developing** the plugin, not just using it. Of course, to develop the plugin, it must be *used* by some Wordpress installation, so it must be in the well known directory, otherwise my development Wordpress installation won't find it and I won't be able to test my changes

Comment: File paths don't matter, git tracks content. You should still be able to merge your change into the originl repo. You just need a branch with the moved files and one with the files at original locations, merge the changes into the branch with the files at the original locations and then make a pull-request.

Comment: I think you're trying to use git as a deployment tool where it's really a source control tool. You should be able to create a tarball for deployment by running `git archive` in the desired subdirectory but can you explain your source and deployment setup a bit further?

Comment: @Polygnome I can't understand this. When you do a `git mv` it's a valid change to the sources, so git must track it. Having `a/b.txt` is different from `a/b/c.txt`. When you merge two branches, git should both change the content of the file and its location, otherwise how can one rely on git to manage his sources?
@CharlesBailey see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone into a location outside your wordpress project, then symlink or copy the correct directory where it belongs, e.g.:

```
$ git checkout git@wherever.org:twitter-plugin
$ cd my-wordpress-site
$ ln -s ../twitter-plugin/twitter-plugin ./twitter-plugin
```

Symlinking may or may not work, since not all PHP functions follow them; if it doesn't, try copying instead. This does mean, though, that you have to copy again when you update the git repo; you probably want to include this procedure in your deployment script.

Comment: Yeah, symlinking is an option to make it work (provided it works...). I've already thought of it, but prefer a *Git solution* if any